# Add Custom Styling to react multi-level dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

[image: enter code here][![text is going outside of the submenu][dedicated resources text is gray color by default]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70ArP.png)
** I am using react-multilevel-dropdown to created drodown and  i want to add custom css to it.text is going outside the submenu at some places. how to fix this??
**

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the style by creating a CSS file. The corresponding classes are provided in the npm documentation. Another way is to inspect elements and change the styles of the corresponding element using your CSS.
Add `!important` after every style

[image]